# how to allow mutilple column search with fulltext search

Tags: php

i'm trying to implement a fulltext search for my website and my problems is that the match() syntax is not allowing use of multiple columns. can anyone help?

here is the code:

```
//
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tenders 
    INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=tenders.category_id 
    INNER JOIN provinces ON provinces.province_id=tenders.province_id 
    WHERE MATCH (details,category, province) 
        AGAINST('$searchterm' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";

$search_count = $db->query($search_sql);

//amount displayed per page
$per_page = 1;
//number of pages
$pages = ceil($search_count->num_rows/$per_page);
```

in the browser, i'm getting an error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dailytenders\search.php on line 39

how can i solve this. i have altered tables to `engine=MyISAM` and `FULLTEXT` on details, category and province columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this:

```
$search_count = $db->query($search_sql);
```

i think that must be this instead:

```
$search_count = $db->query($sql);
```

I used in past the MATCH function against multiple columns and worked good.

Comment: thank you, i have corrected it, however, i am still getting the same error response

Comment: try this: 
`$search_count = $db->query($sql)->fetch_all();`
and in the last line for have the total result:
`$pages = ceil(count($search_count) / $per_page);`